# Error handing with .GOTO in bteq in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

In my bteq I accidentally wrote wrong LABEL name due to that bteq completed with warning as below so there was no data loaded into table.

```
  .IF ACTIVITYCOUNT=1 THEN .GOTO LABEL DELETETBL
 .GOTO LABEL DELETETBL
  *** Warning: Extra text found after command.
          The text 'DELETETBL' not processed (ignored).
```

I need solution to handle above scenario and bteq should fail after this kind of warning. RETCANCEL is not working here.

Comment: You don't use `.GOTO LABEL <label name>`.  It's `.GOTO <labelname>`.

Comment: Right Andrew. In this case I want bteq to complete with errorcode<>0, In 15.0 this will give error not warning but I want to add some checkpoint for this type of mistake in bteq for 14.0

Comment: Are you saying you want to come up with some sort of way in BTEQ to handle syntax errors?

Comment: No Just want to fail the bteq if there is any syntax error.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, and I don't understand why you would want to.  Test your code, if you have syntax errors, fix them.

Comment: Actually we did not got any error message to we missed this bug. That's why I want to add some check from where I can get the error message if there is any syntax issue with .GOTO and other key words.

Answer (score 0):

Call the bteq from unix script and check the return code probably? 4 is the return code for warnings in TD.

Comment: Or a Batch file (among other options) in Windows.
`$?` will return the exit code of last command in most UNIX shells, `%ERRORLEVEL%` will return the same in windows batch file.